# Drupal - OpenLayers - Alter popup behavior

Tags: javascript, drupal, drupal-7

I have modified the popup behavior js file: openlayers_behavior_popup.js directly in the module located at openlayers/plugins/behaviors.

It's working fine per my expected but I do not want to put my own modification in the original module, I want to add it attach to my existing module but I don't know how to do this.

I want the site not to take the behavior at openlayers/plugins/behaviors but follow with my popup behavior code from my own module.

```
Drupal.openlayers.addBehavior('openlayers_behavior_popup', function (data, options) {
    // normal
    var popupSelect = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(layers,
        {
    // my change here!!
        },
        onUnselect: function(feature) {
    // normal
    }
    }
  );
});
```

How can I alter the behavior code of openlayers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issue on this topic by load the modification javascript file in my custom module as following:

```
function mycustom_openlayers_init() {   
     // you might want to load only at some specific page
     // if you want so, please have a look to function arg() of drupal
     // place condition before loading the js file below

     drupal_add_js ( drupal_get_path ( 'module', 'mycustom_openlayers' ) . '/js/openlayers_behavior_popup.js', array(
                'weight' => '9999',
              ) );  
}
```

By specifying the setting of **weight** bigger, my javascript is loaded after loading the original openlayers popup file and then it overrides the behavior of the original to take mine instead.

I don't know if it is the right thing to do but it works for me.

Please let me know if other people could give me a programmatic solution on that and better than above.

Comment: Hi, me too having same problem. didnt find any solution :(
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/123919/control-height-and-width-of-openlayer-popup

Comment: My above workaround solution is working for my current issue even it's not so professional, you can try if it helps

Comment: Yes. I'm following your way only. Thanks for update.